# What is ._.bash_profile file

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin

When I was figuring out how my terminal (Cygwin 64bit on Windows 10 laptop) works, I found a ._.bash_profile file (emphasis on the extra ._). **That was after I tried the command ls -a on the home directory.**

[Terminal displaying all of the files and folders in my home directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsQye.png)

When I typed nano ._.bash_profile into the terminal, I got what I think is just garbled text:
[Click here for the text of the ._.bash_profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Ylr.png)

So my question is what on earth is **._.bash_profile**?

Comment: `file my_mysterious_file_that_has_a_garbled_output` should tell you what it is.

Comment: I'm guessing that you at some point accidentally used `. .bash_profile` as a filename (instead of a `source` command in a shell), and either the tool you wrote it into or a later rename pass replaced the space with an underscore (as is frequently done to simplify operations on filenames)

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the file with an IDE like Visual Studio Code?
It looks like a file with some sort of Mac Os file

Comment: One thing you did get right: I am trying to access a Mac remotely.